# Can We Identify HTTP Request method for a REST Service by just looking at it?

Tags: java, rest, http

Like I have a rest uri : http://localhost:8085/universities/colleges

So if we expose a REST Service, can we tell which HTTP method is supported at server end for this uri?

Comment: That's a link to localhost.

Comment: Short answer: no you can‘t

Answer (score 1):

By just looking at the URL, there's no way of knowing what HTTP methods are supported.

However, you can send an [OPTIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) request to the URL that could potentially return that information.

```
curl -X OPTIONS https://google.com -i | head
```

> HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
>   **Allow: GET, HEAD**
>   Date: Thu, 02 Aug 2018 04:48:44 GMT
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Server: gws
>   Content-Length: 1592
>   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
>   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
>   Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"

Comment: Yes I know this too, but two times I was asked the same question by two different people. I give the same answer and they were not convinced. So just wanted to know is there understanding gap or is it mine? :)

Comment: You're right, and they're wrong. You could try to interpret the URL semantically and hazard a guess about the supported methods, but that's about it.